# Regex in Python to get string of numbers after string of letters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string formatted as `results_item12345`.  The numeric part is either four or five digits long. The letters will always be lowercase and there will always be an underscore somewhere in the non-numeric part.

I tried to extract it using the following:

```
 import re
 string = 'results_item12345'
 re.search(r'[^a-z][\d]',string)
```

However, I only get the leftmost two digits. How can I get the entire number?

Comment: Your regex is currently matching "a single character that is not a-z followed by a single digit".  That should shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: Ah that explains why there were two characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you *only* care about the numbers at the end of the string, the following expression matches 4 or 5 digits at the end of the string.

```
\d{4,5}$
```

Otherwise, the following would be the full regex matching the provided requirements.

```
^[a-z_]+\d{4,5}$
```

Comment: Its backslash, but that's the solution ;)

Comment: Yep, saw that… one second after hitting the button

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to just match any number in the string you could search for:

```
r'[\d]{4,5}'
```

If you need validation of some sort you need to use:

```
r'^result_item[\d]{4,5}$'
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary updated it just before you posted comment... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary thanks, I know that but I prefer to always encapsulate character groups into braces, it's easier for me to read :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re    
a="results_item12345"
pattern=re.compile(r"(\D+)(\d+)")
x=pattern.match(a).groups()
print x[1]
```